# Which architecture I need for use my own DLL in multiple projects?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture

I've this schema actually, 3 projects **in the same solution** :

```
IHM (MVC4) (Reference to BLL Projects)
BLL (Reference to DAL Projects)
    Users
    Tools
    Project_1
    Project_2
DAL
    Users
        QueryUsers.cs
    Tools
    Project_1
    Project_2
```

But I think, I'm in a wrong way because if my project become very huge, it will be difficult to keep a stable website.

I'd like to use this schema : 1 Project and Add Assembly(DLL) Reference :

```
IHM (MVC4)
```

And Create another Solution : For example : Users

In this "Users" Project, I Create 2 sub folders : Core - DAL

```
Project Users
    Core (Definition of what is a user for me)
    DAL
        QueryUsers.cs (Get data in Database)
```

And when I finish this project, in my IHM, I just add an assembly reference.

Questions (same questions) : 
Where can I put all of the DLL that I'll create? 
Because some DLL like "Users" will be use in other projects. But i don't want to duplicate my "Users" assembly... how can I do that?
What do you think about my choice?

Comment: Add separate assembly for the business objects (User etc) to be used in all required assemblies. Could be a good idea to also separate DTOs from actual business objects.

Answer (score 1):

The design you have the moment is perfectly fine, the way I see it you have a nice layered architecture i.e.

- Presentation Layer (IHM)
- Business Layer (BLL)
- Persistence Layer (DAL)

Not sure what you mean by

> But I think, I'm in a wrong way because if my project become very huge, it will be difficult to keep a stable website.

In what way do you think it will become *unstable*? It sounds to me that attempting to create a separate DLL just for your `User` classes is complete overkill. If you need organisation within a specific layer then use folders/namespaces.

Stick with your original design, you have a nice clean separation of concerns and will cope perfectly fine as your system grows.

> Where can I put all of the DLL that I'll create?

Given they are going to be *shared* across multiple applications, consider storing them in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache).

Comment: Why i think it's a wrong way : It's because all projects are in the same solution. If tomorrow I need to create another website but use only some part of the principal project, i can't. That's why i've think of this solution by using DLL.
I don't want to create a separate DLL just for your User but for all projects that compose my Website : Printing, Displaying Data, form control etc.

Comment: You don't *have* to have all the projects in the same solution - however, it doesn't do any harm, in fact it makes development easier as you can just jump to the code instead of opening up the individual project. There are no dependencies with having them in the same solution - on the other hand if you had them in the same *project* then that's a different story. I still don't see what your actual issue is here?

Comment: For example, I create in my BLL the objects obj1, obj2 and obj3. But i need to use these objects in my MVC project AND a command project for example. If I put all of mine objects in my BLL, i can't reuse it in another project excempt if i "include" all of my BLL project. But i don't need all of objects. Just 3 or 4... U see?